Add Bevel to curves when using a solidify modifier for thickness on a imported .svg logo
I have an imported logo .svg file that is in curves. I have eliminated the top faces by using Fill mode: Back.
I now want to add thickness inside the logo itself, so I have used a solidify modifier.
My question is how to add a bevel to this thickness.
I tried using Bevel in Curves in the data properties, but that gives me artifacts on the model. Is there another way to add the bevel, or a better way to thickness without solidify modifier?
The file: 


(Using Blender 3.6.8)
A Bevel modifier can be added after the Solidify modifier, unchecking the Clamp Overlap limiter that is probably confused by such a small geometry:

Resources: 

Side note: May I recommend to scale up your objects, or to change the "Length" parameter in the "Scene/Units" panel to "Millimeters", to avoid such small numbers to edit (and to adjust...) ?

Yeah, I get alot of clipping :)

Thank you by the way, I didn't get the bevel to work, but when I looked at your settings I had Clamp Overlap. So many thanks to you! :)
